# Цвет слова в элементе

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет. Я создал пользовательский элемент управления NumberedTextBoxUC.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NumberedTextBox
{
    public partial class NumberedTextBoxUC : UserControl
    {
        public int SelectionLength;

        public NumberedTextBoxUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            numberLabel.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, richTextBox1.Font.Size + 1.019f);
        }

        private void updateNumberLabel()
        {
            //we get index of first visible char and number of first visible line
            Point pos = new Point(0, 0);
            int firstIndex = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);
            int firstLine = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstIndex);

            //now we get index of last visible char and number of last visible line
            pos.X = ClientRectangle.Width;
            pos.Y = ClientRectangle.Height;
            int lastIndex = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);
            int lastLine = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(lastIndex);

            //this is point position of last visible char, we'll use its Y value for calculating numberLabel size
            pos = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(lastIndex);

            //finally, renumber label
            numberLabel.Text = "";
            for (int i = firstLine; i <= lastLine + 1; i++)
            {
                numberLabel.Text += i + 1 + "\n";
            }

        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateNumberLabel();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_VScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //move location of numberLabel for amount of pixels caused by scrollbar
            int d = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(0).Y % (richTextBox1.Font.Height + 1);
            numberLabel.Location = new Point(0, d);

            updateNumberLabel();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1_VScroll(null, null);
        }

        private void richTextBox1_FontChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateNumberLabel();
            richTextBox1_VScroll(null, null);
        }

        public int SelectionStart { get; set; }

        public Color SelectionColor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

И NumberedTextBoxUC.Designer.cs

```
namespace NumberedTextBox
{
    partial class NumberedTextBoxUC
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.numberLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
            this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).BeginInit();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // numberLabel
            // 
            this.numberLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
            this.numberLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
            this.numberLabel.Name = "numberLabel";
            this.numberLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 267);
            this.numberLabel.TabIndex = 1;
            this.numberLabel.Text = "1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7\r\n8\r\n9\r\n10\r\n11\r\n12\r\n13\r\n14\r\n15\r\n16";
            this.numberLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopRight;
            // 
            // splitContainer1
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.splitContainer1.FixedPanel = System.Windows.Forms.FixedPanel.Panel1;
            this.splitContainer1.IsSplitterFixed = true;
            this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
            // 
            // splitContainer1.Panel1
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.numberLabel);
            // 
            // splitContainer1.Panel2
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
            this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(403, 267);
            this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 41;
            this.splitContainer1.SplitterWidth = 1;
            this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.splitContainer1.Text = "splitContainer1";
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this.richTextBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            this.richTextBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.richTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
            this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
            this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(361, 267);
            this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
            this.richTextBox1.WordWrap = false;
            this.richTextBox1.VScroll += new System.EventHandler(this.richTextBox1_VScroll);
            this.richTextBox1.FontChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.richTextBox1_FontChanged);
            this.richTextBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.richTextBox1_TextChanged);
            this.richTextBox1.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.richTextBox1_Resize);
            // 
            // NumberedTextBoxUC
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
            this.Name = "NumberedTextBoxUC";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(403, 267);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).EndInit();
            this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label numberLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer splitContainer1;
    }
}
```

Это типа textbox, только с нумерацией строк. Я хочу сделать так, что если я напишу в него слово end, оно было красным, а все другие слова станд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подписывайтесь на событие KeyDown/KeyPress/KeyUp, запоминайте нажатую клавишу в буфер (например, в строку), а потом сравнивайте буфер с этим самым "end":

- если "end" не начинается с буфера (например, "en"), буфер очищаете
- если буфер равен "end", подкрашиваете последние три символа от текущей позиции курсора, очищаете буфер